# Able to run Ableton 10 on Wine, but unable to import MP3s

Tags: sound, wine

I've managed to get Ableton 10 running on Ubuntu 16 via Wine. The app seems to run fine, and I am able to drag `wav` files into audio tracks, however I'm not able to do the same with `mp3` files, I get the error "file may be corrupt or not licensed", which typically means the appropriate codec is not installed (https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209774325-Issues-importing-compressed-audio-files-MP3-M4A-FLAC-etc-#corrupt).

I have tried installing various codecs (CCCP, K-Lite, `winetricks windowscodecs`), but with no luck... Ableton 10 is also 64bit only, so I might be doing something wrong there with regards to installing codecs in wine for 64bit maybe? I'm not sure...

I could do with knowing if I am exploring the right avenue, and if so how can I go further troubleshooting this issue... At this point I am half guessing and installing any and all codecs in an attempt to get it to work...

Comment: Depending on your workflow and required features, you might have better luck with something like Ardour that is able to run natively without any translation layers. Back to running apps in Wine, what happens if you load up, say, vlc or a small audio player in Wine? Is this something that only happens with ableton or is it something that happens with anything that doesn't itself decode a given audio file?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with Ableton itself, not with WINE or any codecs. Sometimes, when I try to drag `mp3` tracks to make a mix, on Windows 7 with Ableton 9.0 and 9.5, the same error appears. At other times, Ableton loads `mp3` files without any problems.

I am able to work around the issue by renaming the file extension to `wav`.

Comment: Please edit answer to include following info: Was that native Win7 that also had the problem? When you say "that was it", does that mean the problem went away? Is it in WINE that you are loading other mp3 files? What is the DAW that you are talking about at the end?

Comment: It was native Win7 with the same problem.I mean that with some .mp3 files the DAW(Ableton) gives me the error and with others everything is ok.